# How to keep canvas a fixed size while stretching its container

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas, border

I am trying to make a really simple editor for images. Since the control panel is showed right next to the Canvas, I'd like to put a border between them (I am open to suggestions like a GridSplitter though). I have the Canvas nested in a ScrollViewer nested in a Border. When the image loads in the Canvas, if I resize the window I the image resizes with everything else. Since I am editing this image, I'd like to keep it to its original size and, if the Canvas is to big, use the ScrollViewer to handle that. I don't know if it is more recommendable to put the border around the Control Panel instead.

XAML Code:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="10" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="canvas_RosetteMap" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Canvas Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Grid` instead. `Canvas` are not good at handling resizing, scrolling or anything like that. Here is a simple example that should work with an `Image` also:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="canvas_RosetteMap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid Width="Auto">
            <TextBox Background="Beige" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

Comment: All this is inside a Grid already, should I make another one? Can I edit an Image like I can edit a Canvas for example if I make add a brush functionality to paint over it?

Comment: Indeed, the direct container of your `Image` and the potential `ScrollViewer` should be a `Grid`. If you want to edit your Image, you can add visual element in the `Grid`, on top of your `Image`.

Comment: They are already in a grid. I did not post that, sorry. But they are already inside a grid cell. I am trying to edit the picture, is using Image a better option than Canvas to achieve this?